# Disable automatic scrolling when clicking an item

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qscrollarea

I have a QTreeView with a custom item delegate. The delegate creates an editor that can be very wide (let's say, 2000px width), so the user will scroll horizontally to edit the data.

[image: Step 1]

Image 1: I scrolled to the frame #300. Notice that the scrollbar is already offseted.

[Step 2 http://imageshack.us/a/img801/9887/image2zb.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img801/9887/image2zb.png)

Image 2: I click some part of the editor; then the scrollbar goes to the starting position automatically. It happens because the current selected row have changed. Is there any way to disable the automatic scrolling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with the property [QAbstractItemView::autoScroll](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractitemview.html#autoScroll-prop). So, all I had to do was `myTreeView->setAutoScroll(false);`.